# Showing animation of Views created from a custom adapter

Tags: android

I'm trying to show an animation with all `View`s that I've created from an adapter. When I scroll down, it shows the animation correctly, but when I scroll up, I see these `View`s recreate themselves and show the animation again. Then, when I scroll down, it happens again.

My assumption is that the mechanism of creating a `View` from an adapter is to load the `View` into memory; just the group of `View`s which are on screen right now (but above and below views are not loaded into memory). These will be loaded again when I scroll to these views, right?

Is there any way to fix this problem?

PS: Sorry for my English, I hope you understand my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My assumption is that the mechanism of creating a View from an adapter
>   is to load the View into memory; just the group of Views which are on
>   screen right now (but above and below views are not loaded into
>   memory)

That's somewhat correct: a `ListView` will not try to visualize any data that isn't (at least partially) visible. It also 'recycles' views, meaning that any view that isn't currently used to present data to the user and is of the same 'type' as the next data item, may get reused.

Hence you shouldn't rely on persisting data with or make any assumptions about the existence of particular views. In stead, use something that's separate from the views; e.g. the dataset you're visualizing.

Quite often, you'll supply a list of POJOs to a `BaseAdapter` or `ArrayAdapter`. You could simply add a boolean to the POJO indicating whether it should animate or not, and change that whenever the animation for that particular item finishes. Alternatively, you could keep track of these values in a separate collection (which is probably the more straightforward approach if you're dealing with a `Cursor` as data source rather than POJOs).

Comment: could you give me an example ? i'm very newbie about android development

Comment: Samples are widespread. [Give this one a go](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced_interactive), and make sure you scroll up the page if you're finding it hard to understand what's going on. In your case, you'll want to add a boolean to the `Model` object that indicates whether a list item (and thus its row view) has been animated before. You'll need to change its value whenever the animation finishes and don't start it (again) whenever it has been set.